# No overload matches this call in Next.js/Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, href, react-props, reusability

I got this type error. No overload matches this call.

> Overload 1 of 3, '(props: PolymorphicComponentProps<"web",
> FastOmit<Omit<AnchorHTMLAttributes, keyof
> InternalLinkProps> & InternalLinkProps & { ...; } &
> RefAttributes<...>, never>, void, void, {}, {}>): Element',

Below is my code:

```js
type ButtonProps = {
    onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void; // to handle onClick functions
    children?: React.ReactNode; // make the component able to receive children elements
    color?: 'primary' | 'secondary'; // two styling options (you can create as many as you want)
    disabled?: boolean; // make the button disabled or not
    href?: string;
};

const Button = ({href, children}: ButtonProps) =>{
    return(
        <BtnSection>
         <SignInBtn href={href} >{children}</SignInBtn>
           <Icon src={icon} width="24" height="24"/>
        </BtnSection>
    )
}
```

I tried making my button reuseable by passing `href` as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to fix the problem after so many attempt by removing the question mark in the href propytype Declaration

```
href?: string;
```

now i used this,

```
href: string;
```